# I download audio files but in m3u8 format. How to convert to mp3?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I download audio files but in m3u8 format. How to convert to mp3? tried with ffmpeg. But nothing is downloading at the output, and only some strange characters are visible in the console.

```
def vk_music_get(login,password):

    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login=login, password=password)
    vk_session.auth(token_only=False)
    vk_session.get_api()
    vk_aud = vk_api.audio.VkAudio(vk_session)
    for i in vk_aud.get():
        print(i)
        music_name = i['artist']
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(i['url'], f'\\Users\\AlexK\\PycharmProjects\\MyArchive\\music_vk\\{music_name}.m3u8  ')
    print('VK Download Success! ^_^')
```

When I try ffmpeg, I get these characters

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg should work used like this:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', i['url'], f'{music_name}.mp3'])
```

Make sure the  `i['url']` is the .m3u8 file you want to convert